# Laravel dependency inject service into service

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find the best way to access the InvoiceService from the PaymentService. I have considered DI the InvoiceService like so:

```
protected InvoiceServiceInterface $invoiceService;

public function __construct(InvoiceServiceInterface $invoiceService)
{
    $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
}
```

The issue I have with this method is not all the functions within my PaymentService need the InvoiceService. Is there a way I can get access to the InvoiceService inside the PaymentService a similar way without tightly coupling them together?

I can get the code working by bypassing the interface altogether but this isn't the approach I want to take `(new InvoiceService)->generateInvoice($account, $items, $totalAmount, $totalAmount);`

Comment: But what’s wrong with injection?

Comment: @Maksim I get this error `Too few arguments to function App\\Infrastructure\\Services\\PaymentService`

Comment: Never use new, never. Just inject with constructor. If your PaymentService is too big - split them and inject only what you need.

Comment: I'm using the AppServiceProvider to bind the PaymentService to the PaymentServiceInterface is this where I would inject the InvoiceService? `$this->app->bind(PaymentServiceInterface::class, function () {
            return new PaymentService();
        });`